# C++ template argument with expression

Tags: c++, templates

I am having trouble with C++. I want to be able to put an expression inside a template as an argument.  Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<  ((1>0) ? float : int) > abc() {
}

int main(void){
  return 0;
}
```

This gives me the error:

> main.cpp:11:14: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>   main.cpp:11:14: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>   main.cpp:11:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token

In the end I want to be able to replace 1 and 0 for whatever and also float and int for typename T and U. Why does it think there are two arguments? And how do I solve this?

(Sorry if this is a duplicate I did have a good look for solutions)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `std::conditional`:

```
#include <type_traits> 
std::vector<std::conditional<(1 > 0), float, int>::type> abc() {}
```

Comment: You need parentheses around the `1 > 0` so the compiler will parse it as a conditional expression instead of `vector<std::conditional<1> ...`

Comment: @Casey, Thanks, I thought that was able to be deduced, but I was evidently wrong.

Comment: oops, and a typename. I should really be sober when I'm on SO.

Comment: @Casey, No dependent template arguments (tested just in case and compiles with GCC 4.8.1).

Comment: @Matt, I have to ask now, is there a particular reason for the `typename`? There are no dependent template arguments and it compiles fine without on GCC 4.8.1, but if two others have now edited it in, I'm a bit skeptical.

Comment: @chris: Nope sorry, you are right, I saw Casey's remark and it's a common thing to forget so just edited it in. In hindsight I now understand your follow-up remark whose meaning had eluded me at the time :)